# Content must be able to be shown if one is login page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

this is how I'm going with wordpress forum

it is such that even if you do not log into the site you can see what you can create, etc.

Create forum / post to the site just being tucked away so it is only possible to view it if you are login on the page.

Comment content must also be away but just get some text that you can not write content until he has sustained itself on the page.

I purchased this forum
http://themeforest.net/item/forumengine-flat-responsive-wordpress-forum-theme/5999646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress comes with all the functionality needed for this its as simple as wrapping the content you want within an if statement for example

```
 <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
             echo "Member Content";
       }else{
             echo "Sorry Guest";
 ?>
```

id suggest something like above if you are working with template files you could always wrap the while loop with the above

Comment: Cool;), and I just find that I must write this into the files.